# Match with reges excluding string tags

Tags: c#, regex, tags, windows-phone, match

I am trying to write a code in order to get the matches in a list but without the match tags, until now i have built the following code in WP7 application written on C#

```
public static MatchCollection MatchTags(string content, string string_start, string string_end)
{
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, string_start + "(.*?)" + string_end, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    return matches;
}
```

So how to return matches without string_start, string_end (match tags) without use of replace function after the match extraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works when i get the result with the next code:

```
string my_string_no_tags = matches[number].Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: That was the answer the whole time, but some people want to explore lookaround assertions as a learning experience. But assertions could carry a heavier overhead in time. Just so you know.

Comment: That's it! Thanks for your awnser! x.Groups[1].Value;

Answer (score 1):

Use lookarounds..

```
String.Format("(?<={0}).*?(?={1})",string_start,string_end);
```

---

Though you can also use groups.i.e in your regex `(.*?)` would capture the content within Group 1.**No need** of lookarounds then..

```
MatchTags(content,start,end).Cast<Match>()
                            .Select(x=>x.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: I see that i cannot use MatchTags on wp7, thanks also for comment!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code...

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(content, string.Format("(?<={0}).*?(?={1})", string_start, string_end), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
return matches;
```

Good Luck!